# questions regarding setting up a samba server

Tags: linux, samba

I want to setup a samba for file sharing in my intranet, but I want to know if there is any way to prohibit some kind of files (e.g *.exe) uploaded to the share folder? And I want to know if there is any way to force the user to change the password for the first time login?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`veto files`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#VETOFILES) statement to prevent the upload of exe files. Forcing users to modify passwords is also possible in some circumstances, but I believe this requires running Samba at least as a Domain Controller and your users logging into the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I do not have full answer but hint is use to `veto files` option in your configuration file for your first query. Hint for second query is to use `pdedit` utility.